# Transfer Firebase Photos to G-Drive

Tags: reactjs, firebase, drive

I have a react native project that uploads photos to a firebase DB. Once the last photo is uploaded to Firebase (or even better, while the photos are being uploaded to Firebase), I would like to send copies of these photos to a specified Google Drive folder. I see the link below mentioning transferring to other buckets, but it looks like they are referring to cloud storage server locations.

Any suggestions on the best path to copy (keep photos on both the Firebase DB and Drive folder)?

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#transfer_between_buckets

Answer (score 1):

Okej, I am not sure what you mean when you say "keep photos on firebase db". Do you only save the URL and using firebase storage or are you actually saving the whole photo in base64?

You should use the firebase storage to store your binary files and then you can use cloud function to trigger "onFinalized" and then make a copy of that file into a new bucket.